# Module not found issue

Tags: python

I'm a bit new to running code from the terminal. I am running a test module called `test_blbmktdata.py` from the terminal by running:

```
python -m unittest test_blbmktdata.py
```

And am getting a error:

```
File "C:\Users\stacey\Documents\MERLIN\MERLIN - WORKING\dao_all\dao\iotools\tests\test_blbmktdata.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dao.iotools.blbmktdata import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dao'
```

The folder `dao` does exit:

```
C:\Users\stacey\Documents\MERLIN\MERLIN - WORKING\dao_all\dao\iotools
```

Please see below for the beginning of the module (where the problem is).

```
import unittest
import os.path
from dao.iotools.blbmktdata import *

class TestBlbMktData(unittest.TestCase):
    staticName='StaticInstrumentData.csv'
```

If I run the code from the terminal do I need to change the way I reference imports from different folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

python don't know where to look for the dao model

add the follwoing lines before the import

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<path to prj root directory>)
```

also you will need to have a **init**.py file (empty file) in each directory of the dao so python could recognise it as a module

Comment: Thanks guys.  I have added import sys and 
sys.path.append('C:\Users\stacey\Documents\MERLIN\MERLIN - WORKING\dao_all') for a path to the route of the project and added the init.py files but still get the same error (dao not known) any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: @Stacey can you provide the prj and files structure

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether pythonpath environment variable is properly set. You can refer this.
[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to shahaf's answer, it is worthwhile to look at the official documentation on module resolution : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path